# Is there any way to show the Select MenuItems from specific position at first dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, material-ui

currently I have an array of MenuItems(options) starting from 1900 to 2021 on Material ui. By default when I click the select button, options start from 1900. But I want it to appear from 1982 but at the same time be able to scroll up to 1900 and down to 2021. Is there any ways to handle this? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
The first image is how it is appearing and the second one is how I want it to appear.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `selected` prop in select tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the defaultValue prop for the native Select component.

```
 // To generate array for all options
 const arr = Array(2021 - 1900).fill().map((_, idx) => 1900 + idx);

 <Select defaultValue="1982">
      {arr.map((val) => (
        <MenuItem value={val} key={val}>
          {val}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
 </Select>
```

For controlled components, a default value can be used to initialize the state.

```
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState(1982);
  const handleChange = (event) => {
     setAge(event.target.value);
  };
 
 // To generate array for all options
 const arr = Array(2021 - 1900).fill().map((_, idx) => 1900 + idx);

    <Select
      labelId="demo-controlled-open-select-label"
      id="demo-controlled-open-select"
      value={age}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {arr.map((val) => (
        <MenuItem value={val} key={val}>
          {val}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </Select>
```

[Sandbox Example URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/select-menu-material-ui-gr9ux?file=/demo.js)